# Explain the return value of printf

Tags: c

```
int main (void){
const int y = 99;
printf("%d\n", printf("y = %d", y));
}
```

This program prints "y = 996", I would like help in understanding.

Firstly,

`printf("y = %d", y)` prints out `y = 99`

So the rest of the final expression is:

```
printf("%d\n", "y = 99");
```

But this should be invalid as `%d` expects a number, not a charArray?

Comment: No, `printf` _doesn't_ return the string it has printed. The printing itself is just a side-effect.

Comment: If you had [looked up](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) printf, you would have seen what the return value is.

Answer (score 2):

The `printf` function returns the number of bytes printed.  That value is what is being passed to the second call.

The inside call prints `y = 99` which is 6 characters.  So the outer call receives 6 as the second parameter:

```
printf("%d\n", 6);
```

So the output is `y = 996`.

Answer (score 2):

Let me take a simple example to clear your doubt:

**sample :**

```
 void main(void)
    {
    int b=printf("hellow");
    printf("%d",b);
    }
```

**output:**

```
  6
```

printf("message") is a predefined method which returns *"no. of characters present in the message"* as the above example.

you code:

```
int main (void){
const int y = 99;
printf("%d\n", printf("y = %d", y));   
}
```

**note: After printing the message printf() always returns int value which is no of characters because return type of printf() is int type.**

step 1: Inner printf() function prints 99 first.

step 2: After execution it returns 6 which is no. of characters in the message.

**message is "y = %d"**

step 3: 6 is hold by outside printf() function as :-

```
  printf("%d",6);
```

So, it gives output combinely :

```
 996
```

Answer (score 1):

While `printf` will print out a string to `stdout`, what it *returns* is an integer that represents the number of characters it printed out.

The nested call to `printf`, `printf("y = %d", y)`, prints out 99 and returns 6 because the string `"y = 99"` is 6 characters long, which makes the outer call to `printf`, which takes the return value of the nested call to `printf` as an argument, produce the output 6, giving you the final output of 996.